# problem: showkeys printing labels on top of text in exam class questions

Tags: exam, showkeys

This is the example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,spanish,answers]{exam}


\usepackage{showkeys}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is a question This is a question with the label printed on top.
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The label prints on top of the text so I can't read it.

Is there a fix or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't state what result you hope to achieve but here are a two options based on the `showlabels` package instead of `showkeys`.  If you want the internal label used by `exam` class, use tthe `inline` option.  This does not require any additional information to appear after your questions, as shown below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,spanish,answers]{exam}

\usepackage[inline]{showlabels}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is a question with the label displayed in various places depending on option used. 

        \question Here is another question.

        \question One final question to complete the trilogy series.
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

You can create your own label, which will be located according to other options. You have to place the `\label` command whereever you want want a label. The following example places your custom label in the left margin.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,spanish,answers]{exam}

\usepackage[left]{show labels}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is a question with the label displayed in various places depending on option used. \label{Q\thequestion}

        \question This question has no label.

        \question One final question to complete the trilogy series.\label{Q\thequestion}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\thequestion` is one of the `exam` variables that you can access (see page 29 of the `exam` manual). For other `showlabels` options, see the first page of its manual.

Comment: yes i wanted to see the internal label that the `exam` class gives to the questions because I was getting multiply defined labels and and wanted to see how that worked, but `showkeys` put the label on top of the text so i couldn't see anything. `showlabels` is what I was looking for